# Conditional inputfile , latex

Tags: tables, conditionals, input

I am using a conditionalinput file inside my main file

%% Out2 doesn't exits
%% Out exists

I don't want to get caption and table number at position where I don't have file.

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}   

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testfileexists}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\def\inputtestedfile{\@@input #1 }}
    {\let\inputtestedfile\@empty}%
}
\makeatother


    \centering
    \testfileexists{out}
\captionof{table}{ my cation }
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
   L01&  \inputtestedfile
  \end{tabular} 


\testfileexists{out2}
\captionof{table}{ my caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    L02&  \inputtestedfile
 \end{tabular}


    \centering
\testfileexists{out}
\captionof{table}{ my caption}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    L03&  \inputtestedfile
  \end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

%%%Contents of out.tex

```
\begin{tiny}\begin{tabular}{|l|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
\hline
&\textbf{col 1}&\textbf{col 2}\\\hline
\textbf{row 1}&1.50&1.76\\\hline
\textbf{row 2}&3.52&0.20\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{tiny}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case don't use `\testfileexists` but use `\IfFileExists{<filename>}{<yes>}{<no>}` directly, i.e:

```
\IfFileExists{out}{%
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{ my cation }
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 L01&  \input{out} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}{}
```

If you use `\captionof` and not `table` it's best to wrap the whole thing in a `center` environment. No idea about your placement issues, though.

Comment: @ thanx. It works well